# How can I insert javascript source files into my pyramid python application and use them in my template?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, pyramid

I have redefined this question from the original a bit to make it more fundamental to the question at hand. The relevant parts of my filesystem are as follows.

```
env
    tutorial
        tutorial
            templates
                view.pt
            static
                myjava.js
            views.py
            __init__.py
```

Right now my view.pt template has

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/myjava.js"></script>
```

Then in my `__init__.py`, I have

```
config.add_static_view(name='static',path='env/tutorial/tutorial/static')
```

And finally, the myjava.js file itself is very simple:

```
document.write("hello from the javascript file")
```

I am trying to follow this document: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html

but right now none of the text is showing up. I feel like the problem lies in the paths i am giving it.

Some ideas I have had: in the config.add_static_view, the name='static' is confusing. I want users to be able to visit the url www.domain.com/firstpage, where firstpage is the result of a template that uses a javascript file resource (a file in the static folder). I am worried that these static assets are only for urls that start with www.domain.com/static/... Is this a valid concern? How can I tell the config.add_static_view function to serve the static resources for any views rendered from the view.pt template?

Edit: here is what worked:

in the template, use src="${request.static_url('tutorial:static/myjava.js')}"

then in the **init**.py use config.add_static_view(name='static',path='tutorial:static/')

Comment: Dumb question: is `tutorial/tutorial/static` == `env/tutorial/tutorial/static`?

Comment: I think so? tutorial is my project folder (so the document root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript link, in the template, should be something like `src="${request.static_url('tutorial:static/myjava.js')}"`

This allows your application to be more easily relocated.

This also uses the appropriate asset specification, using the name of the package, 
"tutorial", a colon, then a path relative to the location of the "tutorial" package, which in your case the package is at `env/tutorial/tutorial`.

Edited:  I forgot about the Configurator object.

Here, you want to use a similar asset specification such as `config.add_static_view('static', 'tutorial:static/')`.

You can make different static views for different directories as well, like:  `config.add_static_view('images', 'tutorial:images/')`

When you do things like this, you can move the root of your application to another location, allowing you to have `http://mysite.com/stable/` and `http://mysite.com/devel/` having accesses to `/` be rewritten to `/stable/`.

The static views can be called from any template with code like `${request.static_url('tutorial:images/icons/favicon.ico')}`

Comment: wow very cool. I guess naming the packages instead of the full path is the way to go. I have updated my question with the now working code.

Answer (score 1):

Was reading the [docs here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html) and it looks like when you call `add_static_view` it changes the path of the file? To quote the docs:

> this means that you wish to serve the files that live in /var/www/static as sub-URLs of the /static URL prefix. Therefore, the file /var/www/static/foo.css will be returned when the user visits your application’s URL /static/foo.css.

In your case, since you're  calling `env/tutorial/tutorial/static` "static", you might want to try `src="static/Three.js">` instead

Comment: I think it would be better to use absolute paths: `src="/static/Three.js`, or, better, to use static_url(): http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/url.html#pyramid.url.static_url